# Is it possible to use Omniauth with Devise-JWT?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth

I have Devise and Devise-JWT configured and working for a React single page application using good old email and password. Now, I'd like my users to be able to log in using Facebook/Google/Twitter, etc. Is Omniauth the way to go?

I have Omniauth sort of working with the Developer strategy and I wrote a method that generates the bearer token (I think):

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def developer
    @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"], current_tenant)

    if @user.persisted?
      sign_in @user, event: :authentication #this will throw if @user is not activated
      token = Warden::JWTAuth::UserEncoder.new.call(@user, :user, nil).to_s
      redirect_to # Now what?
```

I'm unsure about what would be the next step, passing the token to the frontend as a URL parameter? That feels kinda risky security-wise, isn't it? This leads me to believe that maybe I'm pushing in the wrong direction here. Am I? How should this be done?

Comment: Because I got cookies to work, I abandoned the need for JWT, which caused omniauth to work pretty much out of the box: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60579293/how-are-cookie-http-only-sessions-supposed-to-work-on-a-spa-with-a-separate-api/60585649#60585649