# How are cookie-http-only sessions supposed to work on a SPA with a separate API server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, session, cookies, single-page-application

When trying to figure out [how to authenticate with Facebook/Google](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60572711/is-it-possible-to-use-omniauth-with-devise-jwt) in the context of an SPA I'm building, someone pointed me to [Stop using JWT for sessions](http://cryto.net/~joepie91/blog/2016/06/13/stop-using-jwt-for-sessions/).

I'm trying to give it a try, using HTTP-Only Cookies. My server is Ruby on Rails with Devise and my client is JavaScript with React, although the conceptual solution is independent of specific tech I believe.

My app gets loaded by going to `projectx.lvh.me` and then it makes a query to `api.projectx.lvh.me` to fetch the current user. At the beginning it's null because the user is not logged in. When a call request is made to sign in, the response from `api.projectx.lvh.me` contains the session cookie, hurra! But the next request that `projectx.lvh.me` makes to `api.projectx.lvh.me` doesn't carry the cookie, so, it seems the cookie is forever lost. Even opening `api.projectx.lvh.me` on another tab doesn't show the cookie. Is this supposed to work? What am I missing?

I thought this was blocked by third-party cookie blocking and that's why we can't use cookies in this scenario and we have to use jwt tokens (stored on a cookie, local storage or session storage).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get cookies working in this scenario by adding `config/initializers/session_store.rb` to my Rails app containing:

```
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: 'session', domain: :all
```

which caused the session cookie to not be for `api.projectx.lvh.me` but for `.projectx.lvh.me`.

On the frontend, the API calls needed to include `withCredentials`, which with Axios it was the `withCredentials` option set to true:

```
Axios.post(`${apiEndPoint()}/users`, { user: values }, { withCredentials: true })
```

and with `fetch` it was the `credentials` option set to `"include"`:

```
fetch(`${apiEndPoint()}/graphql`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    credentials: "include",
    body: JSON.stringify({
        query: operation.text,
        variables,
    }),
})
```